# Formula from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel book with two sheets
Sheet 1: Contains Date which is presented as a list and then a table with values from A-L
Sheet2 : Contains a table with date and serial numbers and values for each col.

Query:
I am doing `Hlookup` from sheet 1 to sheet 2, to get values from sheet 2.
which I am successful.

I do not want to manually copy paste the `Hlookup` formula..as I have a dataset of 200 rows.

I am also writing a formula to display values from Sheet 2 if available if not just maintain Sheet 1 value...

I have the formula written out..I need a way to automatically update the formula in each cell value in sheet 1.

Please find the attached sheet for more information.
I have attached a dummy dataset.

Actual formula looks like:

```
IF(HLOOKUP(C3,'Pec-29'!D3:$X$94,3,0)="","Desk 46",(HLOOKUP(C3,'Pec-29'!D3:$X$94,3,0)))
```

I have an index from 3-235...
I don't want to paste this one by one

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56890064/edit) to include sample data and expected outcome (don't just link to a worksheet). If needed, you can upload screencaps to http://imgur.com and link to them here

Comment: Maybe use row(3:3) instead of 3, then it will change as you copy the rows down? Or just row() if the formula starts in row 3? Or possibly don't use dollars and just address each row in 'Pec-29' e.g. D3:X3 ?

Comment: By the way at time of writing we can't find the attached sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to do this without copying the formula to the other cells then the only solution is to build a macro that loops all the rows and does the same operation as the formula. Below is a generic example of a VBA macro procedure, open the VBA editor with  ALT+F11. Hope it helps.

```
Sub test()
    rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D7:D23")
    For Each cl In rng
        ' do something with this row
    Next cl
End Sub
```